# Why does Lua interpreter output nil?

Tags: lua

In `Lua 5.3.0`, I run "`true and print("Hi")`":

```
> true and print("Hi")
Hi
nil
```

Why does program output `nil`?

Comment: Because print doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `print` function returns `nil`:

```
> print("Hi") == nil
Hi
true
```

The expression `true and nil` returns `nil` (see [Logical operators in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html)):

```
> true and nil
nil
```

That's why your original expression returns `nil`.

Comment: Actually, the `print` function returns nothing, but when used with a boolean operator the number of return values is adjust to one value (which is `nil` in this case). `(print("Hi"))` has the same effect for the same reason, plain `print("Hi")` will not write the `nil` to the console.

Comment: @siffiejoe You are right. It's even more evident at C level where the difference between a Lua function that returns no value and another function that returns a single `nil` parameter is evident. Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 6):

This is a side effect of a new feature of the Lua interpreter in version 5.3.

In previous versions, this code was invalid:

```
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> true and print("Hi")
stdin:1: unexpected symbol near 'true'
```

Similarly:

```
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> 1+1
stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '1'
```

The interpreter only accepted statements, not expressions. You could prefix an expression with `return` or the shortcut `=` though:

```
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> =1+1
2
> =true and print("Hi")
Hi
nil
```

In Lua 5.3 a new feature has been introduced to make it simpler to use the interpreter like a calculator: if the input is invalid, then the interpreter tries to prefix it with `return`. This is why you get this result.